# Caliburn Micro void function can't be triggered inside DialogHost

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, material-design-in-xaml

Normally you can call void function(from ViewModel) in View by simply:

Button Name = VoidFunctionInViewModel

Button Command={Binding Path=VoidFunctionInViewModel}

But when accessing this function inside a DialogHost, the void function isn't triggered.

I have tried retrieving a string field to the DialogHost and it works fine, but when it comes to commands on buttons it doesn't work.

MainViewModel.cs Commands:

```
public async void OpenDialog()
   {
       var confirm = new ConfirmationView{DataContext = this};
       await DialogHost.Show(confirm);
   }
   public void Accept()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("It Failed!");
   }
   public string Success {get; set;} = "Success"
```

ConfirmationView.xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=Accept}" Content="Accept"/>
<Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" Content="Cancel"/>
<TextBlock Name="Success"/>
```

MainView.xaml:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost DialogTheme="Inherit" CloseOnClickAway="True">
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

The Property "Success" is successfully used and shown by the DialogHost.
But the Button "Accept" with the command Accept isn't triggered by the DialogHost.

The Button "Cancel" is working, with the command from materialDesign.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt it be this way for caliburn.micro?

```
<Button x:Name="Accept" Content="Accept"/>
```

Using the Command="" syntax works only by using ICommand or RelayCommand in the ViewModel, or? At least that is how i understood caliburn.micro so far.

If that doesnt work, you could try this. This worked for me in the drawerHost, where caliburn.micro Command binding failed for me:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Accept()]" Content="Accept" />
```

other sources with dialog examples, which might be usefull:

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs

https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXaml.Examples

Comment: Thank you so much! the addition of the line
cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Save()]"
with Content="Accept" actually did the job for me!