# WPF MVVM Binding x:Name not triggering method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm new to WPF, started trying to learn it on Wednesday.  I have started looking into Caliburn.Micro and MVVM and I have used MaterialDesignInXAML Nuget package for a material design in the app. From this I have created a basic application that I want to use.  This app has drawer menu that slides out from the side.  On this menu, I have a number of buttons.  I want to be able to click these buttons and have my ContentControl Update with the relevant UserControl Views I have created.  I have `LoadHome()` in the public `ShellViewModel(){LoadHome();}` Method and this loads when i start the app, however clicking the buttons in the menu does not update the contentcontrol nor does it trigger any break points, even thought it is using the same `x:Name=""` syntax the others use.  If i take the buttons off the menu and place them after, The button click works as expected and updates the contentcontrol.

**My Code**

## **ShellView.XAML**

```
 <DockPanel>
                           <Button x:Name="LoadHome"
                            Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                        HOME
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="LoadBlobPurge"
                            Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                            materialDesign:RippleAssist.Feedback="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    Self}, Path=Foreground, Converter={StaticResource BrushRoundConverter}}"
    >
                        BLOB PURGE TOOL
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.CloseDrawerCommand}"
                            Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                        APP 2
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.CloseDrawerCommand}"
                            Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                        APP 3
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.CloseDrawerCommand}"
                            Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                        CLOSE
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="LoadHowTo"
                            Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="About" />
                    </Button>
                    
**ShellViewModel.cs**

        public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            LoadHome();
        }

        public void LoadHome()
        {
            ActivateItem(new HomeViewModel());
        }

        public void LoadBlobPurge()
        {
            ActivateItem(new BlobPurgeViewModel());
        }

        public void LoadHowTo()
        {
            ActivateItem(new HowToViewModel());
        }

        public void LoadApp2()
        {
            
        }

        public void LoadApp3()
        {
            
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where are the commands for the button set? Note that people make MVVM to be a thing...for one can roll their own w/o needing other tools. I provide an example on my blog [Xaml: MVVM Example for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017). With that said, you may have too many things going on in this question to answer it properly and would need to clarify it better.

Comment: Please don't post **all** code you have. Only post a **minimally required** portion to showcase your issue. Consider reading the [ask] topics and especially about the [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Caliburn.Micro you can try to use the following syntax on the button.  x:Name binding also failed me when using MaterialDesignInXAML.

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action LoadBlobPurge()]"
                    Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                        materialDesign:RippleAssist.Feedback="{Binding RelativeSource= 
   {RelativeSource Self}, Path=Foreground, Converter={StaticResource BrushRoundConverter}}">                       
LOAD BLOB PURGE </Button>
```

I found a more in depth answer in relation to this here:

[Caliburn Micro void function can't be triggered inside DialogHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400056/caliburn-micro-void-function-cant-be-triggered-inside-dialoghost/58426243#58426243)